# Literals or expressions in unit test asserts?

Tags: tdd, expression, assert

Do you prefer literal values or expressions in your Asserts in your unit tests? This little example demonstrates what I mean - please pay attention to the comments:

```
[Test]
public function fromXML_works() : void {
    var slideshow : Slideshow = SlideshowConverter.fromXML(xmlSample);

    // do you prefer literal value "1":
    assertEquals(slideshow.id, "1");

    // ... or an expression like this:
    assertEquals(slideshow.id, xmlSample.@id);
}


private var xmlSample : XML =
    <slideshow id="1">
        <someOtherTags />
    </slideshow>;
```

The nice thing about the expression is that when the XML sample changes, the unit test will not break. On the other hand, I've basically provided an *implementation* of one aspect of my SlideshowConverter directly in my unit test which I don't like (the test should test intent, not implementation). I can also imagine that tests using expressions will be more prone to programming errors (I could have, for example, made a mistake in my E4X expression in my test method).

What approach do you prefer? What advantage is usually more important on real world projects?

Answer (score 2):

Particularly since you've tagged this TDD: stick with literals.  Writing a test before code exists to pass it, you say to yourself, "Self: if I had this function and gave it those parameters, then *this* is what I would get back."  Where *this* is a very specific value.  Don't hide it away; don't abstract it - just put the value into the test.  It enhances the documentation value of the test as well.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to use constants within my tests - it ensures that the test fixtures are simple and straightforward.  Plus, as you mention, it avoids programming errors in the test itself, which may hide programming errors in the real code.